# PacketReceived/Sec value is very high

Tags: c++, qt, networking, wmi

```
class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface : Win32_PerfRawData
{
    uint32 BytesReceivedPerSec;
    uint32 BytesSentPerSec;
    uint64 BytesTotalPerSec;
    string Caption;
    uint32 CurrentBandwidth;
    string Description;
    uint64 Frequency_Object;
    uint64 Frequency_PerfTime;
    uint64 Frequency_Sys100NS;
    string Name;
    uint32 OutputQueueLength;
    uint32 PacketsOutboundDiscarded;
    uint32 PacketsOutboundErrors;
    uint32 PacketsPerSec;
    uint32 PacketsReceivedDiscarded;
    uint32 PacketsReceivedErrors;
    uint32 PacketsReceivedNonUnicastPerSec;
    uint32 PacketsReceivedPerSec;
    uint32 PacketsReceivedUnicastPerSec;
    uint32 PacketsReceivedUnknown;
    uint32 PacketsSentNonUnicastPerSec;
    uint32 PacketsSentPerSec;
    uint32 PacketsSentUnicastPerSec;
    uint64 Timestamp_Object;
    uint64 Timestamp_PerfTime;
    uint64 Timestamp_Sys100NS;
};
```

this WMI Class.

I get PacketReceived/sec but its value higher than 120000.
I think its bytesreceived per sec.
I got other values and its correct

```
int WMIClass::ExcuteQuery(const char* cstr,LPWSTR atrb)
{
  hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t(cstr),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

   while (pEnumerator)
   {
    hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);
    if(0 == uReturn)
    {
        break;
    }
    VARIANT vtProp;

    // Get the value of the Name property
    hres = pclsObj->Get(atrb, 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

    intVal=vtProp.uintVal;
 }
return intVal;
 }
```

Program excutes normally and values can be read easily but I have doubt on this value.
I need packet recieved per sec on network adapter.
Any simple solution? if in Qt framework, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see where `intVal` is initialized, if it is a member variable you may be running into a previous value being returned or returning the value of uninitialized memory. In your code you should be handling the `Get` operation failing, whether it be from an unknown property name or other failure; if it fails you should return an error value or throw and exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're properly initializing intVal:

```
int WMIClass::ExcuteQuery(const char* cstr,LPWSTR atrb) {
    int intVal = 0;

    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t(cstr),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    while (pEnumerator) {
        hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
            break;

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hres = pclsObj->Get(atrb, 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);

        intVal = vtProp.uintVal;
    }

    return intVal;
}
```

Comment: Still that range I got these values
PacketReceived/Sec=4453164
PacketReceived/Sec=4453444
PacketReceived/Sec=4453724
PacketReceived/Sec=4454004
PacketReceived/Sec=4453164
PacketReceived/Sec=4453444
PacketReceived/Sec=4453724
PacketReceived/Sec=4454004

Comment: I think, It is BytesReceived/Sec value.

Answer (score 1):

Win32_PerfRawData returns the raw counter value so is not actually 'per second'. 
You need to use the Win32_PerfFormattedData values to get that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @X-trade, A bit more information about your answer, like pointing on reference can be a good idea.